# Receive average scores and check the number of scores in a range | Java

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

Write a java program that reads the grades of 10 students, which is from 1 to 100, from the entrance, specifying that the scores of some people are from 90 to 100, some people are from 60 to 89 and some people are from 1 to 59. The program should print the average scores at the end.
This is code for average, how can i add else and if or while to review how much numbers are in range 1 to 59 or 60 to 89 or 90 to 100?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EhsanNp {

    public EhsanNp() {
        String getStr = getUserNums();
        double result = userAvg(getStr);
        printAverage(result, getStr);

    }

    public String getUserNums() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter ten numbers separated by spaces: ");
        return in.nextLine();
    }

    public static double userAvg(String str) {
        String[] arr = str.split(" ");
        double sum = 0.0;
        double average = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
        }
        if (arr.length > 0) {
            average = sum / arr.length;
        }

        return average; // how do I get the program to count what to divide by since user can input 5- 10?
    }

    public static void printAverage(double average, String userNumInput) {
        System.out.printf("The average of the numbers " + userNumInput + "is %.2f", average);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new EhsanNp();

    }
}
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and post ten sample numbers as well as the averages you expect to get from those ten numbers. Do you want the average of all those whose grade was between 60 to 89?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add three variables which store the number of grades between 1 to 59, 60 to 89 and 90 to 100 and increment them in the for loop. For example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EhsanNp {

    int lowGrades;
    int middleGrades;
    int highGrades;

    public EhsanNp() {
        lowGrades = 0;
        middleGrades = 0;
        highGrades = 0;
        String getStr = getUserNums();
        double result = userAvg(getStr);
        printAverage(result, getStr);
        
    }

    public String getUserNums() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter ten numbers separated by spaces: ");
        return in.nextLine();
    }

    public static double userAvg(String str) {
        String[] arr = str.split(" ");
        double sum = 0.0;
        double average = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
            if (Integer.parseInt(arr[i]) >= 1 && Integer.parseInt(arr[i]) <= 59) {
                lowGrades++;
            }
            else if (Integer.parseInt(arr[i]) >= 60 && Integer.parseInt(arr[i]) <= 89) {
                middleGrades++;
            }
            else {
                highGrades++;
            }
        }
        if (arr.length > 0) {
            average = sum / arr.length;
        }

        return average; // how do I get the program to count what to divide by since user can input 5- 10?
    }

    public static void printAverage(double average, String userNumInput) {
        System.out.printf("The average of the numbers " + userNumInput + "is %.2f", average);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new EhsanNp();

    }
}
```

Then you can do whatever you want with the variables like displaying them for example.

Comment: Thank you; When I get output I can not get what I want.
Let me explain more.
I want if the user enters the numbers 1, 34, 56, 80, 99, 75, 60, 29, 33 and 86; Check these numbers and display them in a categorized form as follows:
The numbers 1, 29, 33, 34 and 56 are in the first category (between 1 and 59), which is a total of 5 numbers.
The numbers 60, 75, 80 and 86 are in the second category (between 60 and 89, which is a total of 4 numbers.
The number 99 is also in the third category (between 90 and 100), which is a total of 1 number.

Comment: If you want to display the numbers in a ascending form, you should look at a sorting algorithm like "Quicksort" or "Insertion Sort". There a plenty of tutorials on the internet on how to implement a sorting algorithm in Java. Have a look at https://www.baeldung.com/java-quicksort for example.

Comment: I do not want to sort; I just want to count the numbers in the specified interval that there are several numbers in each interval; Do you have a way to do this?

Comment: I am sorry I do not quite understand what you want to do. If you want to count how many numbers are in your specified Intervals have a look at my code example. After running the program you should have the values you are looking for stored in the variables lowGrades, middleGrades and highGrades. If you want to do something different, please try to explain again what you want to do.